# How to change variable with react-native onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am training in react-native, but I have some comprehension problems.

Why can change the "modalVisible" variable, but I cannot change "aux".

```
const App = () => {  

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(0);    
  var aux = 0;    
  const _onPress  = (code) => {
    aux = 1
    setModalVisible(code)
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style = {styles.centeredView}>
        <View style = {styles.box}>
        <Pressable
            onPress = {() => _onPress(modalVisible+1)} 
            style={styles.pressable}
          > 
            <Text style = {{color:'black'}}>{modalVisible} {aux}</Text>
          </Pressable></View> 
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I deleted some views, so it's not ready for a 'crtl + c' 'crtl + v'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the state of variable using `useState` hooks, the re rendering of the component take place and the new updated value is shown.

In case of regular variable, `aux` in this example, even though the value is changed, the re rendering does not occur and the new updated value is not shown.

There is a similar questions here: [useState hooks and regular variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58252454/5669120)

Answer (score 1):

you need use `setState` To cause new render

just add

```
const [aux, setAux] = useState(0);
```

then to change it  use `setAux(1)`